# How to add value to textbox in asyanc TASK in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

Hi I am new to win Form and i want to display the progress of below task in textbox on form but I was unable to do so.

```
 // Create progress printing and querying tasks
    Task progressPrintTask = new Task(() =>
    {

        IJob jobQuery = null;
        do
        {
            var progressContext = new CloudMediaContext(_accountName, _accountKey);
            jobQuery = progressContext.Jobs.Where(j => j.Id == job.Id).First();
           // AppendTextBox("Indexer Job started");
           //  textBox2.AppendText(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", DateTime.Now, jobQuery.State, jobQuery.Tasks[0].Progress));
            //  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", DateTime.Now, jobQuery.State, jobQuery.Tasks[0].Progress));
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
        while (jobQuery.State != JobState.Finished &&
               jobQuery.State != JobState.Error &&
               jobQuery.State != JobState.Canceled);
    });

    progressPrintTask.Start();
```

Please check screen shot more detail

[image]

Please help

Comment: `but I was unable to do so` What did you try? Why didn't it work? Exceptions?

Comment: @ChrFin I am getting values in Console.write but when I am assigning that value in text box then nothing is displayed.

Comment: Is it possible you get an exception in you debug output? Are you awaiting the `progressPrintTask` somehwere?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing an invoke:

```
// Create progress printing and querying tasks
Task progressPrintTask = new Task(() =>
    {

        IJob jobQuery = null;
        do
        {
            var progressContext = new CloudMediaContext(_accountName, _accountKey);
            jobQuery = progressContext.Jobs.Where(j => j.Id == job.Id).First();
            textBox2.Invoke(() => textBox2.AppendText(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", DateTime.Now, jobQuery.State, jobQuery.Tasks[0].Progress)));
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
        while (jobQuery.State != JobState.Finished &&
               jobQuery.State != JobState.Error &&
               jobQuery.State != JobState.Canceled);
    });
progressPrintTask.Start();
```

Comment: My application freeze when I used this